# Java: regular expressions to parse the "edges" of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

Java novice here.

Say I'm given a string:

> ===This 銳is a= stri = ng身===

How would I use pattern-matching to efficiently figure out how many "=" signs there are at the edges of "This 銳is a= stri = ng身"?

Also, I'm trying to use Java escape sequences such as \G, but apparently they don't compile.

Comment: Are you asking for the regex to do the matching or a way to get the count?

Comment: The answer is 3. And `\G` works just fine in Java, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Why would you use a regex for that?

Comment: @Qtax Wouldn't the answer be 6, because there are 3 equal signs on each edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally probably *wouldn't* use a regex for this, but ... this is what works:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(=+).+[^=](=+)$").matcher("===Som=e=Text====");
m.find();
int count = m.group(1).length() + m.group(2).length();
System.out.println(count);
```

(Note this isn't doing error checking and assume there are `=` on both ends)

**Edit to Add:** And here's one that works regardless if there's `=` on either end:

```
public static int equalsCount(String source)
{
    int count = 0;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(=+)?.+[^=](=+)?$").matcher(source);
    if (m.find())
    {
        count += m.group(1) == null ? 0 : m.group(1).length();
        count += m.group(2) == null ? 0 : m.group(2).length();
    }

    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(equalsCount("===Some=tex=t="));
    System.out.println(equalsCount("===Some=tex=t"));
    System.out.println(equalsCount("Some=tex=t="));
    System.out.println(equalsCount("Some=tex=t"));
}
```

On the other hand ... you could avoid the regex and do:

```
String myString = "==blah=";
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
while (myString.charAt(i++) == '=')
{
    count++;    
}
i = myString.length() - 1;
while (myString.charAt(i--) == '=')
{
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that...that's how I'd do it in C...must be something to do with the whole "Strings are immutable in Java" thing.

Comment: My background is in C; I'm a terrible Java programmer ... always wanting to just get things done rather than using a framework or a design pattern ;)

Comment: For the given problem, using Pattern.compile("^(=+).+(=+)$") is just enough. Is there any special reason for using [^=] in between?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the number of occurrence of "=" at the edges then try this.

```
int count = str.length() - str.replaceAll("[^=]=[^=]", "").length();
```

Comment: You're missing the vital part of the question, *"are at the edges"*. Hint: Add some anchors, quantifiers and an alternation.

Comment: That would return the count of all equal signs, not just the ones which border "This 銳is a= stri = ng身".

Comment: It would also remove equals in the text. Im not sure if it will get all, though. `"[^=]+(=[^=])*` should work  better.

Comment: @Arian It would not, because strings are immutable.  An even cleaner approach would be `^=+|=+$` as the pattern.

Comment: This has naught to do with strings being immutable. `replaceAll` returns a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one probable answer:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    String str = "===This is a= stri = ng===";
    Pattern edgeEq = Pattern.compile("=");
    Pattern wordEq = Pattern.compile("[^=]=+[^=]");

    Matcher edgeMatch = edgeEq.matcher(str);
    while (edgeMatch.find()) {
        count++;
    }

    Matcher wordMatch = wordEq.matcher(str);
    while (wordMatch.find()) {
        count--;
    }

    System.out.println(count);
}
```

This will help you find the number of `=` on the edges of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always the same number of `=` at the start as at the end:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^=*").matcher(s);
int count = m.find()? m.group(0).length(): 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
    String s1 = "===This 銳is a= stri = ng身===";
    System.out.println("Length : "+s1.length());
    p = Pattern.compile("^=+");

    m = p.matcher(s1);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find())
    {
        count = m.group().length();
        System.out.println("Group : "+m.group());
    }


    p = Pattern.compile("(=+)$");
    m = p.matcher(s1);
    while (m.find())
    {
        count += m.group().length();
        System.out.println("End Group : "+m.group());
    }

    System.out.println("Total : " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `=` at the edges are balanced you can use

```
^(=+).*\1$
```

Group1's length is the length of `=` at the edges